# Использование Emmet VS code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Использую сокращение.

```
a.link*6
```

Вылетает такая каша -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, как починить.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Добавил вам код текстом, используйте блоки для кода в следующий раз

Answer (score 3):

1. Нажмите <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. В строке введите `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`

и добавьте в ваш `setting.json` следующее

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
        "inline_break": 1
        },
},
```

После этого результат будет такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]